# Is there a way to match "Empty" sequences/nodesets

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

Every now and then I want to match missing elements, i.e. an empty sequence/nodeset

(this is completely untested/run...its just for illustation and could be any XSLT version)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="stuff/SomeStuff"/>
       <xsl:if test="count(stuff/SomeStuff) = 0">
          <xsl:call-template name="noStuff"/>
       </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="noStuff">
      <bar/>>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="SomeStuff">
      <foo/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

bit clumsy, be quite nice to go something like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="stuff/SomeStuff"/>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Empty(SomeStuff)">
      <bar/>>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="SomeStuff">
      <foo/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

is this lurking somewhere i can't find? I think an empty sequence is 'special' enough to have something. In a functional language the sequence would exist as a datatype you could match directly on, so it feels missing to me, a bit like matching Some/None on an Option/Maybe.

Comment: Templates match *nodes*, not *sequences*. You can write a template to match some node, but if the node does not exist, then the template will not be executed.

Comment: Can't you do something like : stuff[not(SomeStuff)]

Comment: Suggested reading: https://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/

Comment: In XSLT 3, you can match on any item, i.e. a node or a string or a number, a boolean, an xs:date or xs:dateTime. But you can't match on the empty sequence.

Comment: @Sebastien - ah...nice...let me knock something up, but if you want to write that as an answer I think that works quite well, i.e. you match on the parent and then match inside it.

Comment: @Sebastien - if you want to post an answer I will mark yours and the answer - just copy/paste mine if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like : `stuff[not(SomeStuff)]`

Example :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="stuff"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="stuff[not(SomeStuff)]">
      <bar/>>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="stuff">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="SomeStuff"/>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template match="SomeStuff">
      <foo/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 3.0 has an instruction xsl:on-empty allowing

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="stuff/SomeStuff"/>
   <xsl:on-empty>
      <xsl:call-template name="noStuff"/>
   </xsl:on-empty>
</xsl:template>
```

The semantics aren't quite the same: this is testing that the *output* of the apply-templates is empty, not that its *input* is empty.

The drafts for XSLT 4.0 have an `otherwise` operator, allowing

```
<xsl:variable name="noStuff" as="element()">
  <noStuff/>
</xsl:variable>
...
   <xsl:apply-templates select="stuff/SomeStuff otherwise $noStuff"/>
...
<xsl:template match="noStuff">
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: its not complete clear to me the semantics of "on-empty" (and the saxon docs arent especially clear), does this mean, IF the output document (for this template) is empty, then call noStuff

Comment: You don't want to look at Saxon docs for this, you want to look at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#on-empty - essentially, if the preceding instructions produce no visible output, xsl:on-empty kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

So based on sebastiens comment

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="stuff"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="stuff[not(SomeStuff)]" priority="1">
      <bar/>>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="stuff">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="SomeStuff"/>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template match="SomeStuff">
      <foo/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which to be fair, matches how you would do it in a FPL.

having actually written the code in a proper context, its actually quite verbose in anything but a trivial context, because you have to pass all the parameters through - in most FPs these would be 'captured' as the match would be inside the calling code.

It IS the sensible answer, just not as cost free as hoped.

Comment: The priority attribute is unnecessary: the pattern with the predicate has a default priority of 0.5, compared to 0 without. Note that this is not really different from your original "clumsy" attempt; you can use a single template with an if/choose, or 2 templates with predicate/s.

Comment: I dislike the priority rules in XSLT - so I make them explicit

Comment: ironically I may revert to the "clumsy version" its shorter and more cohesive to read.

Comment: The example is too contrived to express an opinion on which is more expedient. Re your added note about parameters: in XSLT 2.0 and higher you can define parameters to "tunnel".

Comment: ah ok, I'll look it up

Comment: ah...tunnelling is something you declare when passing the parameter, so tbh, you still have to pass the parameters at least once, in which case, the contrived example is typical rather than atypical, and I stand by the opinion

Comment: actually sorry...the contrived example IS atypical because its too simple, the "proper context" is much more typical, and you end up passing parameters that you don't with the "clumsy" approach...the opinion is based on a more typical realistic context, barely more complex.